# "How to ask" area disappears when I scroll down if I don't close all of the error messages

Tags: bug, asking-questions

If you submit a question without filling in the title, body or tags, error messages appear. When the error messages come up, the "How to ask" area is grayed-out. If you scroll down to the point where the grayed-out "How to ask" panel passes above the top of the screen, it suddenly disappears.

---

Link to screen recording of bug in action: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxRMbmixnUEoQm9mUkM2RU9GeFk

---

[image]

Grayed-out "How to ask panel."

---

[image]

Scroll down a little...and it suddenly disappears!

---

**NOTE:** *I'm not simply scrolling it out of view.* When the top edge of the "How to ask" panel touches the top of the browser, it just vanishes.